# Mapping from a node's name to its index and vice versa in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

Given a `networkx` graph, is there a way to map from a node's name to its index in the adjacency matrix and vice versa?

I know that `G.nodes()` returns a list where the index of the node in the list corresponds to its index in the adjacency matrix.

So to map from a node's name to a node's index, I'm doing a very stupid way of storing the node's index in a dictionary and map it by the node's name.

To map from a node index to its name, then I create another dictionary similar to the one before (with the keys and values switched).

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: not as far as I know.  I have a bunch of code similar to yours, though with a few improvements.

The first thing you can do is remember that each node has a dictionary hanging on it.  `G.node[node_name]` is a dictionary of whatever you want.  You can thus do something like:

```
G.node[node_name]['index'] = G.nodes().index(node_name)
```

Which at least hangs the information on the graph, but in the same fragile way as your method: if you modify your graph the behaviour of G.nodes() isn't documented.

A probably-better solution is to use the `nodelist` kwarg for `G.adjacency_matrix`.  This takes a list of node names and outputs the adjacency matrix in that order.  You can thus set up the list in a sensible-for-your-application way, rather than the pseudorandom behaviour of G.nodes().  For instance, you can pass it a sorted list of your nodes (`sorted(G.nodes())`) if the nodes are named in a useful way.

Answer (score 1):

For small / moderate graphs, one simple option is to store the node names as a list:

```
nodes_list = np.array(list(g.nodes()))
```

To recover the name from the index, e.g:

```
node_name = nodes_list[4]
```

To recover the index from the name:

```
node_id = np.where(nodes_list == "n4")[0][0]
```